# How to test iOS app with appium from Jenkins on MacOS

Tags: automated-tests, appium-ios

is there a possibility to test an iOS app (which is already installed from AppStore) from jenkins on the macOS machine without an apple developer account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. In order to test on a real phone using appium, you will need an Apple developer account.